# multiple cursor using Npgsql?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

I'm used to (from Ada using libpq) to

- open a cursor
- get some key values
- use those key values as bind parameters for other statements.

But I get a Npgsql.NpgsqlOperationInProgressException
instead.

I once got this working with sql-server, but solved it via adding 'MARS' to the connect string (Multiple Active Record Sets)

Can I do something like that here to?

Here what I'm trying to do:

```
            conn.Open();

        // Define a query
        NpgsqlCommand cmdGetSelectionIds = new NpgsqlCommand("select distinct(R.SELECTIONID) from ARUNNERS R, AMARKETS M " +
                                              "where true " +
                                              "and M.MARKETID = R.MARKETID " +
                                              "and M.MARKETTYPE = 'WIN' " +
                                              "and R.STATUS <> 'REMOVED'", conn);


        NpgsqlCommand cmdNumWins = new NpgsqlCommand("select count('a') from ARUNNERS R, AMARKETS M " +
                                              "where true " +
                                              "and M.MARKETID = R.MARKETID " +
                                              "and R.SELECTIONID = @selid " +
                                              "and M.MARKETTYPE = 'WIN' " +
                                              "and R.STATUS = 'WINNER'", conn);

        NpgsqlCommand cmdNumPlcs = new NpgsqlCommand("select count('a') from ARUNNERS R, AMARKETS M " +
                                              "where true " +
                                              "and M.MARKETID = R.MARKETID " +
                                              "and R.SELECTIONID = @selid " +
                                              "and M.MARKETTYPE = 'PLACE' " +
                                              "and R.STATUS = 'WINNER'", conn);

        NpgsqlCommand cmdNumLosses = new NpgsqlCommand("select count('a') from ARUNNERS R, AMARKETS M " +
                                              "where true " +
                                              "and M.MARKETID = R.MARKETID " +
                                              "and R.SELECTIONID = @selid " +
                                              "and M.MARKETTYPE = 'WIN' " +
                                              "and R.STATUS = 'LOSER'", conn);

        NpgsqlDataReader drGetSelectionIds = cmdGetSelectionIds.ExecuteReader();

        while (drGetSelectionIds.Read())
        {
            selid = drGetSelectionIds.GetInt32(0);


            cmdNumWins.Parameters.AddWithValue("selid", selid);
            using (NpgsqlDataReader drNumWins = cmdNumWins.ExecuteReader())
            { 
                if (drNumWins.Read()) numWins = drNumWins.GetInt32(0);
            }

            using (NpgsqlDataReader drNumPlcs = cmdNumPlcs.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (drNumPlcs.Read()) numPlcs = drNumPlcs.GetInt32(0);
            }

            using (NpgsqlDataReader drNumLosses = cmdNumLosses.ExecuteReader()) {
                if (drNumLosses.Read()) numPlcs = drNumLosses.GetInt32(0);
            }

            Console.Write("selid : {0} \t num W {1} \t num P {2} num L {3} \t points {4}\n", selid, numWins, numPlcs, numLosses, (3.0*numWins + numPlcs )/(numWins+numLosses));


        }
        // Close connection
        conn.Close();
```

Yes, I could read the first statement into a list and loop over that,
but I do have got quite some legacy code that is build like the above.

/Björn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is NpgSql only allows a single data reader to be open at a time.  If you have a situation where you need more than one data reader open against the same connection at the same time, I would argue there may be a better way of reaching your end goal.

So, disclaimer...  don't do this.  BUT, if you wanted to do what you described above, this would be a way to accomplish it:

```
cmdNumWins.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@selid", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
cmdNumPlcs.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@selid", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
cmdNumLosses.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@selid", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));

List<int> idList = new List<int>();

using (NpgsqlDataReader drGetSelectionIds = cmdGetSelectionIds.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (drGetSelectionIds.Read())
        idList.Add(drGetSelectionIds.GetInt32(0));

    drGetSelectionIds.Close();
}

foreach (int selid in idList)
{
    cmdNumWins.Parameters[0].Value = selid;
    cmdNumPlcs.Parameters[0].Value = selid;
    cmdNumLosses.Parameters[0].Value = selid;

    numWins = Convert.ToInt32(cmdNumWins.ExecuteScalar());
    numPlcs = Convert.ToInt32(cmdNumPlcs.ExecuteScalar());
    numLosses = Convert.ToInt32(cmdNumLosses.ExecuteScalar());

    Console.Write("selid : {0} \t num W {1} \t num P {2} num L {3} \t points {4}\n", selid, 
        numWins, numPlcs, numLosses, (3.0 * numWins + numPlcs) / (numWins + numLosses));
}
```

The better way would be to do this all as a single query:

```
select
  r.selectionid,
  count (1) filter (where m.markettype = 'WIN' and r.status = 'WINNER') as win,
  count (1) fitler (where m.markettype = 'PLACE' and r.status = 'WINNER') as place,
  count (1) filter (where m.markettype = 'WIN' and r.status = 'LOSER') as lose
from
  arunners r
  join amarkets m on m.marketid = r.marketid
where
  r.status != 'REMOVED'
group by
  r.selectionid
```

I may have missed some nuances about your logic, but hopefully you get the idea.  This should do in one fell swoop, quickly and efficiently, what your C# logic is doing.  It will be much friendlier to the database and for large datasets should be quite a bit quicker.

Comment: I say that this answers the question via 'The problem is NpgSql only allows a single data reader to be open at a time'. And yes there are som typos in my question, but the main question was if there is a possibility to have several open cursors on one connection. And the code above may or may not be written as one query - but I was wondering in more general terms - in order to port some legacy code where this is a common pattern.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the use case.  My full-time job is database and .NET programming, and I can't think of a single time where this approach was necessary.  That doesn't mean it won't ever be, but I have never encountered one that wasn't better handled another way (better = less code, more efficient, faster performance).  If you have a real-world example, I'd love to better understand and perhaps might even have some thoughts on how to handle it

Comment: I maintain and develop a legacy system. In that system, the mentioned approach exists. Get a cursor and loop through a recordset, and updating something else, where input comes from the cursor you are looping over. Above that was showed as counting records given some variable data from the looping cursor. This legacy system is a candidate for rewrite in .net core. I'm looking at different approaches to translate the logic of that system. But it is clear that the old pattern will not do. We intend to run it on Oracle/sql server/Postgresql - on Linux and Windows. But I am now looking at Dapper.

Answer (score 0):

As was written above, Npgsql indeed allows only one data reader to be open on a given connection at the same time (unlike MSSQL's MARS feature). However, you can do something a bit similar [by manually using server-side cursors yourself](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html). In other words, you can run one query and fetch X rows from its cursor, then execute a second query based on the output from the first. You can always go back to the first query and fetch X more rows, etc.

In other words, while Npgsql doesn't allow more than one *reader* at the same time, PostgreSQL does allow more than one *query* (or cursor) at the same time.